# Remove Error class when user starts typing in input

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm using an ajax call to submit a `FORM`. I want to highlight all the inputs that fail validation and then remove the highlight as soon as they start entering into the input field. I am able to add the error class but I cannot get it to be removed. I have tried numerous things including calling events on keydown, keypress, keyup, change, focus, etc..

For everything I've tried, either nothing happens or the alert gets fired off only ONCE immediately after submitting.

Here's what I have right now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#config_form_submit').off().click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#config_form').submit();
});


function removeErrorClass() {
    alert($(this).html());
}

// $("input .error").keyup(removeErrorClass());
//$("input .error").change(removeErrorClass());
//$("input .error").keydown(removeErrorClass());
//$(".error").on(keypress, removeErrorClass());


$('#config_form').off().submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: $('#config_form').attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#config_results").text(data.message);
            if(data.errors.length > 0)
                for(index in data.errors) {
                    $("#id_"+data.errors[index]).addClass("error");
                    $("#id_"+data.errors[index]).bind("input", removeErrorClass());
                }
        },
    });
});
}); //document.ready
```

Comment: A jsFiddle would be nice here! http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I haven't used bind before but it looks like you may be using `.bind` incorrectly. If the element identified by `"#id_"+data.errors[index]` is not the input element, make sure that the selector identifies the input element. And secondly, change `.bind("input",...` to `.bind("change",...`

Comment: What about the HTML and CSS?

Comment: It looks like the error is in the reply of the server. Did you do a console log of the returned data?

Comment: You're trying to attach handlers to elements (`input.error`) which do not yet exist, you need to use event delegation: `$('#config_form').on('keyup', 'input.error', function() { ... });`

Comment: The element is an input field, and the response is correct. When I addClass("error") it works perfectly fine and when I inspect the element it's on the input field.

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle, I could investigate a bit more closely

Comment: I added:  #("#config_form").on('keyup', 'input.error', function(){
     console.log("test");
    });
and for some reason it submits a GET instead of a POST now, which causes errors on the backend

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide a jsfiddle, the html is a django template form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with a variation of billyonecan answer:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input.error", function(){
    $(this).removeClass("error");
});
```